# Ignore directories while Unix find

Tags: unix, directory, find

I was trying to make  Unix "find" not to list the directories while searching for a particular file.

```
find  <path> -name filename <Dont't list matching directories>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find  <path> -name filename ! -type d
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-type` argument, so you probably want to include `-type f` to match only files.

Answer (score 0):

- find   -name filename  -type f
  OR
- find   -name filename  -not -type d